# Am I including npm modules in my chrome extension correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, graphql, browserify

I'm working on a chrome extension that grabs data from Rate My Professor's GraphQL API using the [@mtucourses/rate-my-professors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mtucourses/rate-my-professors) module, and then putting that rating on my universities courses portal. When I attempt to use the module in VS Code:

```
const ratings = require('@mtucourses/rate-my-professors').default;

(async () => {

    const profName = 'Hossein Kassiri';
    const basicProfInfo = await ratings.searchTeacher(profName, 'U2Nob29sLTE0OTU=');

    const id = basicProfInfo[0].id;
    console.log(basicProfInfo);
    //console.log(id);

    // get the profs avg rating
    const profInfo = await ratings.getTeacher(id);
    const avgRating = profInfo.avgRating;

    //console.log(profInfo);
    console.log(avgRating);
    console.log("https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/professor?tid=" + profInfo.legacyId);

})();
```

It works as expected (returns professor info/rating).

However, if I try to mimic the same functionality in a chrome extension, it does not work (basicProfInfo is an empty object). I am using browserify to pack background.js, as it imports the @mtucourses/rate-my-professors module.

My content.js:

```
const professorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('td[width="15%"] a');

professorLinks.forEach(link => {
  const professorName = link.textContent;
  console.log(professorName);
  
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ professorName }, (response) => {

    console.log(response);

    if (response.error) {
      link.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div>Error: ${response.error}</div>`);
    } else {
      link.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div>${response}/5</div>`);
    }

  });
});
```

and my background.js:

```
const ratings = require('@mtucourses/rate-my-professors').default;
console.log("background.js loaded");

async function getAvgRating(profName) {

  const basicProfInfo = await ratings.searchTeacher(profName, 'U2Nob29sLTE0OTU=');
  
  console.log(basicProfInfo);
  if (!basicProfInfo || basicProfInfo.length === 0) {
    return { error: 'Professor not found' };
  }

  const id = basicProfInfo[0].id;
  const profInfo = await ratings.getTeacher(id);
  const avgRating = profInfo.avgRating;
  console.log(avgRating);
  
  return avgRating;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log('received message from content script:', request);
  console.log(request.professorName);

  getAvgRating(request.professorName).then(response => {
    sendResponse(response);
  });
  return true;
});
```

I tried using other tools to pack my extension instead of browserify (like extension CLI), but basicProfInfo still returns an empty object.

The expected output for basicProfInfo is:
[test.js, in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4upF.png)

but the actual output (in Google Chrome) is an empty object:
[content.js/background.js, in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCCOa.png)

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly-- I see the content.js output in the F12 developer console, and I see the background.js output in the chrome DevTools window. I declared both files in the manifest.json, but I'm having trouble packing my extension with the npm modules inside of it. Also, does popup.html need to be apart of the extensions src? This is all I have right now: https://github.com/mahfoozm/YorkURMP

Comment: The code looks correct, my first guess was wrong. It may be a problem of the ratemyprofessors API which fails when invoked from an extension. Use devtools network panel in the extension's background page and find differences to the successful request e.g. headers, etc.